# Crashing app. Android. OnClick Shared Preferences

Tags: android, onclick, sharedpreferences

App keeps crashing at the onclick. No errors in debug. Crashes at editor.apply() or at start next activity. Can't figure out why. When it crashes it goes to a white screen then reloads the main activity. Using android studio and a kindle. Tried the simulator and it still didn't work. Tried rewriting and checking the permissions nothing has worked. The rest of the app works fine and I access shared preferences in other activities. Any help is good. Thank you.

```
package com.jakewalther.x;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class newUser extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText ename, eemail, enumber,eage, epin;
Button button;
String malefem;
String name, email, number, pin, age;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_user);

    ename = findViewById(R.id.Name);
    eemail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
    enumber = findViewById(R.id.Phone);
    epin = findViewById(R.id.Pin);
    button = findViewById(R.id.create);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox boxM = findViewById(R.id.Male);
            CheckBox boxF = findViewById(R.id.Female);

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("info", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

            editor.clear();

            if (boxM.isChecked()) {

                if (boxF.isChecked()) {
                    malefem = "Trans";
                } else {
                    malefem = "Male";
                }
            } else if (boxF.isChecked()) {
                malefem = "Female";
            }

            name = ename.getText().toString();
            pin = epin.getText().toString();
            email = eemail.getText().toString();
            number = enumber.getText().toString();
            age = eage.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor sex = editor.putString("sex", malefem);
            SharedPreferences.Editor username = editor.putString("username", name);
            SharedPreferences.Editor password = editor.putString("pin", pin);
            SharedPreferences.Editor xmail = editor.putString("email", email);
            SharedPreferences.Editor phone = editor.putString("phone", number);

            SharedPreferences.Editor ager = editor.putString("age", age);
            editor.apply();

            Intent next = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoadXOrgasm.class);
            startActivity(next);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You can't store null value in `SharedPreferences`. So, make sure you didn't try to store any null value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are creating a lot of instances of `Editor` object.

Try to do it like this way :

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences("info",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
     editor.putString("sex", malefem);
     editor.putString("username", name);
     editor.putString("pin", pin);
     editor.putString("email", email);
     editor.putString("phone", number);
     editor.putString("age", age);
     editor.apply();
```